# Subscription between Orion context broker and Quantumleap works, but table is not created in CrateDB

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, crate

Cheers!

I've been working for a couple of months with Fiware, using Quantumleap and CrateDB to store historical data (which will then be displayed in Grafana).

I have created about 14 successful subscriptions through Postman for different sensors, but for the past couple of weeks I am struggling to create a new additional subscription.

Below I share the JSON that I am using to create this subscription (following the format that I have used in previous subscriptions):

```
{
    "description": "Suscripcion a cambios de contexto CALCULATION",
    "subject": {
        "entities": [{
            "idPattern": ".*",
            "type": "CALCULATION"
        }],
        "condition": {
            "attrs": [
                "ActivePowerConsumedA1",
                "ActivePowerConsumedA2",
                "ActivePowerConsumedA3",
                "EnergyShareA1",
                "EnergyShareA2",
                "EnergyShareA3",
                "EquivalentTrees",
                "FR1_B11_20Efficiency",
                "FR1_B18_10Efficiency",
                "FR1_B18_12.5Efficiency",
                "FR2_B11_20Efficiency",
                "FR2_B18_10Efficiency",
                "FR2_B18_12.5Efficiency",
                "GeneratedEnergyDayA1",
                "GeneratedEnergyDayA2",
                "GeneratedEnergyDayA3",
                "GeneratedPowerA1",
                "GeneratedPowerA2",
                "GeneratedPowerA3",
                "MI_B10_5Efficiency",
                "PowerShareA1",
                "PowerShareA2",
                "PowerShareA3",
                "SL_B11_28Efficiency",
                "TotalActiveEnergyConsumedDay",
                "TotalActivePowerConsumed",
                "TotalEmissions",
                "TotalEnergyShare",
                "TotalGeneratedEnergy",
                "TotalGeneratedEnergyDay",
                "TotalGeneratedPower",
                "TotalPowerShare"
            ]
        }
    },
    "notification": {
        "attrs": [
            "id",
            "ActivePowerConsumedA1",
            "ActivePowerConsumedA2",
            "ActivePowerConsumedA3",
            "EnergyShareA1",
            "EnergyShareA2",
            "EnergyShareA3",
            "EquivalentTrees",
            "FR1_B11_20Efficiency",
            "FR1_B18_10Efficiency",
            "FR1_B18_12.5Efficiency",
            "FR2_B11_20Efficiency",
            "FR2_B18_10Efficiency",
            "FR2_B18_12.5Efficiency",
            "GeneratedEnergyDayA1",
            "GeneratedEnergyDayA2",
            "GeneratedEnergyDayA3",
            "GeneratedPowerA1",
            "GeneratedPowerA2",
            "GeneratedPowerA3",
            "MI_B10_5Efficiency",
            "PowerShareA1",
            "PowerShareA2",
            "PowerShareA3",
            "SL_B11_28Efficiency",
            "TotalActiveEnergyConsumedDay",
            "TotalActivePowerConsumed",
            "TotalEmissions",
            "TotalEnergyShare",
            "TotalGeneratedEnergy",
            "TotalGeneratedEnergyDay",
            "TotalGeneratedPower",
            "TotalPowerShare"
        ],
        "http": {
            "url": "http://quantumleap:8668/v2/notify"
        },
        "metadata": [
            "dateCreated",
            "dateModified"
        ]
    }
}
```

As expected, I get HTTP response code **201 Created**

Additionally, when I query OCB for subscriptions, I get, among the existing subscriptions created, the one I just created:

```
{
    "id": "6388cc5324c929752900e240",
    "description": "Suscripcion a cambios de contexto CALCULATION",
    "status": "active",
    "subject": {
        "entities": [{
            "idPattern": ".*",
            "type": "CALCULATION"
        }],
        "condition": {
            "attrs": [
                "ActivePowerConsumedA1",
                "ActivePowerConsumedA2",
                "ActivePowerConsumedA3",
                "EnergyShareA1",
                "EnergyShareA2",
                "EnergyShareA3",
                "EquivalentTrees",
                "FR1_B11_20Efficiency",
                "FR1_B18_10Efficiency",
                "FR1_B18_12.5Efficiency",
                "FR2_B11_20Efficiency",
                "FR2_B18_10Efficiency",
                "FR2_B18_12.5Efficiency",
                "GeneratedEnergyDayA1",
                "GeneratedEnergyDayA2",
                "GeneratedEnergyDayA3",
                "GeneratedPowerA1",
                "GeneratedPowerA2",
                "GeneratedPowerA3",
                "MI_B10_5Efficiency",
                "PowerShareA1",
                "PowerShareA2",
                "PowerShareA3",
                "SL_B11_28Efficiency",
                "TotalActiveEnergyConsumedDay",
                "TotalActivePowerConsumed",
                "TotalEmissions",
                "TotalEnergyShare",
                "TotalGeneratedEnergy",
                "TotalGeneratedEnergyDay",
                "TotalGeneratedPower",
                "TotalPowerShare"
            ]
        }
    },
    "notification": {
        "timesSent": 3,
        "lastNotification": "2022-12-01T15:49:09.000Z",
        "attrs": [
            "id",
            "ActivePowerConsumedA1",
            "ActivePowerConsumedA2",
            "ActivePowerConsumedA3",
            "EnergyShareA1",
            "EnergyShareA2",
            "EnergyShareA3",
            "EquivalentTrees",
            "FR1_B11_20Efficiency",
            "FR1_B18_10Efficiency",
            "FR1_B18_12.5Efficiency",
            "FR2_B11_20Efficiency",
            "FR2_B18_10Efficiency",
            "FR2_B18_12.5Efficiency",
            "GeneratedEnergyDayA1",
            "GeneratedEnergyDayA2",
            "GeneratedEnergyDayA3",
            "GeneratedPowerA1",
            "GeneratedPowerA2",
            "GeneratedPowerA3",
            "MI_B10_5Efficiency",
            "PowerShareA1",
            "PowerShareA2",
            "PowerShareA3",
            "SL_B11_28Efficiency",
            "TotalActiveEnergyConsumedDay",
            "TotalActivePowerConsumed",
            "TotalEmissions",
            "TotalEnergyShare",
            "TotalGeneratedEnergy",
            "TotalGeneratedEnergyDay",
            "TotalGeneratedPower",
            "TotalPowerShare"
        ],
        "onlyChangedAttrs": false,
        "attrsFormat": "normalized",
        "http": {
            "url": "http://quantumleap:8668/v2/notify"
        },
        "metadata": [
            "dateCreated",
            "dateModified"
        ],
        "lastSuccess": "2022-12-01T15:49:09.000Z",
        "lastSuccessCode": 500,
        "covered": false
    }
}
```

When I go into CrateDB to verify the creation of the table, it simply does NOT show up.

Am I doing something wrong with this particular subscription?

What should I do to get this table to appear in CrateDB? since I need it to continue advancing in a project

I am attentive to the comments and I am very grateful for the collaboration.

I tried deleting and recreating the subscription and even the entity, hoping that after doing so, the table would be created after creating the subscription again.

The table was never created.

I tried to download the CrateDB service, whose version used is 5.0.0 and, after uploading it again, waiting for the table to appear, it still did not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution i found was to modify the entity type, both in the context entities and in the subscription. For some reason, a table for entity type "CALCULATION" was not being created in crate